# how to get returned rows from a sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I want to get rows count from follow query:

```
select c1,count(*) from table    
group by c1 having count(*) > 1;
```

so I write sql statement in SQL server like below:

```
select count(*) from (    
select c1, count(*) from table   
   group by c1 having count(*) > 1);
```

but when I run this script, I always get an syntax error that means there is a syntax error near last parenthesis. but this sql statement works fine in Oracle.

can anybody tell me how should I write it in SQL server correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQL Server` requires `alias` name to the sub-selects. Add the missing `alias` name to the sub-select to fix the error.

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   (SELECT c1, 
               Count(*) cnt
        FROM   table 
        GROUP  BY c1 
        HAVING Count(*) > 1) a; --here
```

However there is a simpler version

```
SELECT TOP 1 Count(*)OVER() -- Distinct Count(*)OVER() 
FROM   table 
GROUP  BY c1 
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: yes, you're right, but I also need to set an alias name to the second column in the sub query, set it as 'cnt' or something like that

Comment: @user2575502 - yeah, missed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `with` to create temporary result set and then run another query over it:

```
with mytable
as
(select c1, count(*) as cnt from table   
 group by c1 having count(*) > 1)
select count(*)
from mytable
```